# How can I export all users in a CSV format?

Tags: users, importing-exporting

A site we have over 8000+ users with Views, Ctools and VBO installed. Is it possible to export all users data into 1 CSV file? We tired [Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) with no luck(memory limit), even we increase the memory to 128MB. Please help.

Comment: As I mentioned on my question. The Views Data Export does not help on my situation.

Comment: @H-L "You have the option to turn on batch export, for large datasets" Source: https://drupal.org/node/1820452

Comment: Thank You Alexar! the Batch export does solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick the following in a file named `expusers.module`

```
<?php
/**
 *  Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function expusers_menu() {
  $items['expusers'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_expusers_select',
    'access arguments' => array('administer expusers'),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Callback
 */
function _expusers_select() {
  // 
  $csvfile_name = 'expusers.csv'; // the file to save to
  $users = array();
  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {users}');
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    unset($userarray);
    foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
      $userarray[] = (empty($value)) ? '' : '"' . $value . '"';
    }
    $user = implode(',',$userarray);
    $users[] = $user . PHP_EOL; // Remove this if file_save_data don't work.
    // Use PHP statement below to append to file here if file_save_data don't work.
    // file_put_contents(..path to file.., $user, FILE_APPEND); 
  }
  $file = file_save_data($users,'public://' .$csvfile_name); // Remove this if file_save_data don't work.
  return '<p>CSV dump of {users} table written to file "' . $file->uri . '".</p>';
}
```

Stick the following in a file named `expusers.info`;

```
name = Export users
description = "Exports the {users} table to a CSV file in the public file area."
core = 7.x
```

Create a directory named `expusers` in your in your `modules` directory, and place both files in it.

Enable the custom module "Export users" on the site's module page.

Navigate to the path `expusers` (e.g. `http://example.com/expusers`).

The message:

```
CSV dump of {users} table written to file "public://expusers.csv".
```

Should appear.

Go to your public file area and pick up your file.

The above tiny custom module should be far less resource hungry than **Views data export**, so, hopefully, you will get your CSV without hitting a memory limit .

However, it first collects *all* the user data into an array in memory, before dumping into the file.

If you still hit a memory limit, you can't use Drupal's very convenient `file_save_data` to save to a file.  Instead, you must save the data one line at a time.  There is no built-in Drupal function to do this, but you should be able to use PHPs `file_put_contents` instead.

I've used comment to indicate how to change the code to replace Drupal's `file_save_data`  with PHP's `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Ty @Free Radical. Its a small and great module. I have to use this if the site getting bigger. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider for addressing these requirements is the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

You would use it's report writing features (such as its WYSIWYG report writer and/or it's query builder) to first create a report that fits your needs. The result of it could be a tabular output and/or graph. After the report content matches the specifications, you could save it as (e.g.) a CSV file.

Here is a quote from one of the forena community docu pages, i.e. [Reasons for considering Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187):

> Reports created by Forena (combined with SVGGraph and mPDF) can be
>   saved (exported) as PDF documents with embedded graphs. Other
>   supported formats for saving a report are CSV, XLS, DOC, HTML, etc.

The Forena [Video demos and tutorials](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187) contain quite some links to live demos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple function (D7):

```
/**
  * Export all active users into CSV.
  */
function foo_export_users_csv($filename = 'users-' . REQUEST_TIME) {
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $filename . '.csv');
  $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {users} WHERE status = 1", array());
  $csvdata = 'Uid,Username,Email,Created,Access,Login' . PHP_EOL;
  foreach ($results as $record) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = $record->uid; 
    $row[] = $record->name; 
    $row[] = $record->mail; 
    $row[] = $record->created; 
    $row[] = $record->access; 
    $row[] = $record->login; 
    $csvdata .= implode(',', $row) . PHP_EOL;
  }
  print $csvdata;
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Then call this function from hook_menu, some submit function or somewhere else, like:

```
/**
 * Some callback function.
 */
function foo_export_users_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // Set unlimited time for large sizes.
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  $op = $values['operation'];
  switch ($op) { 
    case 'export':
      foo_export_users_csv();
      break;
  } 
}
```